# SQL - Invalid object name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are the steps to understand what happened (I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017):

1. I imported an Excel file as a table
2. I renamed my table to `dbo.export`
3. To test, I created a new query and simply wrote the statement `SELECT * FROM dbo.export` - it runs fine
4. I save my query
5. I close SSMS
6. I reopen SSMS and open my query
7. When I try to execute my query now, it gives me the error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1. Invalid object name 'dbo.export'

I made no changes to anything. My code now suddenly doesn't work. Is SQL Server somehow changing the object type of my table? I really have no idea what's the issue since I changed absolutely nothing.

Comment: When you imported the excel sheet, it has created a database for you... that DB must have a name (let's say MyTestDataBase). When you reopen the management console, make sure you select that database.

Comment: I suspect you are pointed to the master database.   USE yourdatabasename

Answer (score 4):

You are probably in the master database. 
Either select your database where it says "master" in SSMS:
[image]

or use the name of the database in your query like this:

```
DBNAME.dbo.export
```

or in the beginning of the query, type

```
USE DBNAME;
```

And then go on with your query `SELECT * FROM export;`

Answer (score 1):

You must have created a Database for importing the excelsheet. Make sure you select the same database when you run the query:

[image]

In the example above, `AdventureWorks2012` is the selected Database.

Alternatively you can include the DB name in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM myDbName.dbo.export
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the database in the first line then use your selection query:

`USE databaseName;`

`SELECT * FROM export;`

Answer (score 1):

When you close your query the default database will change to the master database.

Every time you open a query, you should select the database. Choose one of these ways.

1) Select your database from the combo-box on toolbar on top of the SSMS menu.

2) Just write this command before your T-SQL statement.

```
 USE 'place your database name'
```